# Fill pandas multi_index dataframe empty hours with nearest (previous) time

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe with the following structure:

| Time | Company | Product_type | Total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 06:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 20 |
| 2021-01-31 05:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 13 |
| 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 4 |
| 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00 | Nike | Shoes | 5 |
| 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 3 |
| 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00 | Nike | Shoes | 3 |

What I need to do is to "fill" the time_hour gaps with the nearest previous value (time) according to their company and product_type. In this case, for Adidas, a row for the 04:00 is missing so it'll need to be filled with 4, the value from 03:00 sales.

| Time | Company | Product_type | Total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 06:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 20 |
| 2021-01-31 05:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 13 |
| 2021-01-31 04:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 4 |
| 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 4 |
| 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00 | Nike | Shoes | 5 |
| 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00 | Adidas | Shoes | 3 |
| 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00 | Nike | Shoes | 3 |

I know how to do it in the case of using a datetime as the unique index but this multi_index setting is something I couldn't solve for the moment.

Comment: `df.asfreq('H').ffill()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to make sure that the Time column is a datetime column.

```py
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Then we need to upsample the times to generate missing hours for each `Company` and `Product_type`.

```py
df = df.groupby(['Company', 'Product_type']).resample(on='Time', rule='1H').sum().reset_index()
```

This gives us

```
  Company Product_type                      Time  Total_sales
0  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00            3
1  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00            4
2  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 04:00:00+00:00            0
3  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 05:00:00+00:00           13
4  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 06:00:00+00:00           20
5    Nike        Shoes 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00            3
6    Nike        Shoes 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00            5
```

Then we can fill the zeros with the closest previous hour's data.

```py
result = df.sort_values(['Company', 'Product_type', 'Time']).replace(0,np.nan).ffill()
```

`Result` is

```
  Company Product_type                      Time  Total_sales
0  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00          3.0
1  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00          4.0
2  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 04:00:00+00:00          4.0
3  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 05:00:00+00:00         13.0
4  Adidas        Shoes 2021-01-31 06:00:00+00:00         20.0
5    Nike        Shoes 2021-01-31 02:00:00+00:00          3.0
6    Nike        Shoes 2021-01-31 03:00:00+00:00          5.0
```

Comment: This works great and solves the posted problem. But there's an additional problem I forgot to mention. What to do if today is 2021-02-05 and there's no more data available? I'd like to still fill all the hours between the last date with a value and the current date. Is there a simple way to add that?

Comment: That's great. If if solved the answer could you please mark the answer as accepted? RE: the other question, please start a new question to clarify your intent, and desired outputs etc. and I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thanls @mullinscr new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064076/fill-dates-with-last-value-until-current-time